# How to debug image processing projects on eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, image-processing, eclipse-plugin, embedded

Here at work we have plenty of experience developing image processing applications for the TI DSP platform using an old version of code composer (CC 3.3). We are transitioning to the ARM platform using Eclipse (flavored and distributed by Xilinx).

In the old code composer, a feature we used a lot was to look was an IDE widget that could display a certain area of memory as a bitmap image. It had a properties grid where you would define things like size, pixel format and stride orientation to properly interpret the blob of memory as a picture. The tool also had some nice features like zooming, a grayscale counter, line profile, histogram and etc.

Is there something similar for eclipse? If not, how difficult would it be to create one? I mean, how difficult it is to create a barebones plugin for eclipse that draws information from a location of memory in a jtag interface?

Comment: I wonder if there exists support for eclipse... I mean, someone I can call for these type of questions. Or in this case would it be Xilinx?

Comment: Really? Nobody? That is the first time I ask something here and nobody makes even a single comment.

Comment: Eclipse is open source, but most companies develop their own plugins to work with their HW, so you can try TI or Xilinx. Maybe they have one which you might be happy with, or may they are interested in building one...

Comment: I was looking for such a feature for Eclipse to integrate with my Code Composer Studio 6. I am shocked if there is a Code Composer specialized image displaying IDE widget. How can I use it then?

Comment: HALCON comes with a visual studio plugin for this, but it's hooking into their backend that manages all of the image memory management. I too want something like this, badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has no such feature; personally, I work in a similar environment (image processing on a DaVinci architecture + Eclipse IDE). Writing a Eclipse plugin is not a overly complicated task - there a loads of tutorials(like [this one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html)). But maintaining it may become one. We have referece Code in QT so we don't need such features. but if you really want something similar I guess you can always do a memdump in a binary file and interpret hat as an image. As long as the format isn't anything spacial (e.g. you are dumping jpeg format) it should be fine.

Comment: could you elaborate on the memdump? where do you type that command? and what do you mean by "reference code in QT"?

Comment: well, eclipse, like most ides was save/load memory feature where you specify the address, the size(of offset) and the how you want the information written to the dump file (text, bin)..and that's it really. About our system: the code which runs on the target has a VS+QT equivalent so you can debug it in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Gdb can call python script. If gdb is used for debugging then please use this. You can use OpenCV or PIL or any image library to show the image.

Updated on 2 Apr 2014:

Let 'data' be the pointer to the image.
Inside gdb run "python data = gdb.parse_and_eval("data")". This will give access to inferior's memory pointed by data.
e.g., "python print(data[35])" will show the 35th element of 'data'.

As the image data can be read in python, it can be displayed or analysed.

Following links will help in getting things done:

1. http://www.cinsk.org/wiki/Debugging_with_GDB:_How_to_create_GDB_Commands_in_Python
2. https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python

Note: Please ignore the comment I added. Hit enter key before writing the actual info.

Hope this helps.

Comment: could you provide a sample on how to call the script from GDB and more importantly, how to access target memory from python?

Answer (score 1):

That is a great idea for static objects but what if your memory is created temporarily on the heap or on the stack? Is isn’t it easier in dynamic environments (using openCV) just to put a three lines of code whenever you need to see some buf content as an image and use Qt to do image scaling and histogramming?

```
Mat I(h, w, CV_8U, buf);
imshow(“winname”, buf);
waitKey(-1);
```

I heard that the latest version of openCV highgui module has the options you talked about but I personally see only very limited use of it in a dynamic programming environment. And yet I visualize data all the time. Moreover, I like to interact with my images, for example, rotate them in 3D, click and get values, or to mark a certain segment. I guess it will be hard to do this with a specific plug-ins.

Comment: First of all, thanks for at least trying to respond.

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP, we have been using CC for a decade now and we use this all the time. Imagine you set a breakpoint and you just want to visualize a block of memory as an image. In CC, you simply give the plugin a memory address, image size, pixel format and voila, it shows the image for you. And it also provides some nifty features that help with image analysis. If I don't find a plugin like that, I'll probably have to make one. Not sure how difficult it will be though.

Comment: BTW, we use our own image processing algorithms that use specialized hardware for fast processing.

Comment: Thanks Padu, I felt that I was missing something and visualizing while debugging and stopping at an interruption point was the case. Without the plug-in I cannot do this (I work in Eclipse on Ubuntu). So far I am aware only about such a plug-in called ImageWatch for MS: http://opencv.org/image-debugger-plug-in-for-visual-studio.html

Comment: I used that one before, but for VS I've ended up creating my own.

Comment: Do you have one that would work for Eclipse under Ubuntu/Mac?

Comment: You might look for your specific org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.IVariableValueEditor extension. If I got it right, you need to interpret a certain member field as an image, right?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this; haven't tried it yet:

https://github.com/cuekoo/GDB-ImageWatch

If eclipse is calling gdb, maybe there is a way...